# How to save user profile image using Alamofire to MYSQL database then retrieve on the following screen

Tags: ios, mysql, swift3, uiimage

I am creating a user profile and I would like to save the user's image to my MYSQL database. originally, I was saving the user's Gender, birthday & relationship status to the User class, however I have decided to add a user profile image. That additional code is below:

```
  func updateUser(UserGender: String, UserBirthday: Date, UserStats: String, UserImage: UIImage, completion: @escaping (String?, String?) -> Void) {
    let dicParams = [
        "user_gender"   : UserGender,
        "user_birthday" : UserBirthday,
        "user_stats"    : UserStats,
        "user_image"    : UserImage
        ] as [String : Any]

    Alamofire.request("\(Constants.Server.URL)/users",
        method: .put,
        parameters: dicParams,
        headers: header)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value as [String: String]):
                completion(value[Constants.Server.RESPONSE_MESSAGE], nil)
            case .failure(_):
                completion(nil, self.getErrorString(ErrorData: response.data!))
            default:
                completion(nil, "Unkown Error")
            }
    }
}
```

I am curious since it is an image if I need to use UIImageJPEGRepresentation or include any additional information in the request, or when I call it on the following screen to fill a UIImageView to wrap it as UIImage object. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but parameters will appear in the URL of the PUT request, so I am unsure what specifying either a date or an image will actually do. Alamofire might be smart enough to convert the date into a suitable string, but the image? You probably want to put binary data into body of the request. And I haven't a clue about best practices of storing and retrieving binary data from an SQL db.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to save directly in database. When you download image, save it to documents directory of your app and save its path to database. Wherever you need to show, just read image from documents directory as you have its path in your database and set it to imageView.